# Weird TPS peaks on SQL 2005 replicated database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication

When monitoring the Transactions/Sec using perfmon on one of my SQL2005 replicated databases - I'm seeing the TPS increase to 1000 and then immediately drop back down again - this happens every 5 seconds.

I'm not sure what's causing this - is this something to do with replication?

We also have asynchronous statistics set on this particular database.

I've tried profiling when the users are not connected - but nothing is writing to the database.

[image]

**ADDED PICTURE AND BOUNTY**

Comment: So is that a screenshot of an actual TPS Report? ;-)

Comment: Well, TPS from PERFMON when the system isn't in use (Sunday).

Answer (score 0):

When you ran the profiler, did you exclude all filters so all events would show?